# What are the differences between the processes run by npm command:

Tags: node.js, express, npm, npm-run

Recently I made a simple API server using node.js+express. And the script below is a part of my package.json file I use to run with npm commands.

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "release": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production MODE=release node server/app.js",
}
```

After I starts the server with ***npm run release***, I can see multiple processes such as below are running on my Linux server.

```
/bin/sh /api/node_modules/.bin/cross-env NODE_ENV=development MODE=test node server/app.js
node /api/node_modules/.bin/../cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development MODE=test node server/app.js
node server/app.js
```

I read a related documentation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/run-script.html), but I don't understand what actually happens in background.

1. What is the order of creating processes? npm => /bin/sh => node /api/.. => node server/app.js ?
2. What does each process do? All three processes are necessary to run my server?
3. If I wants to kill the server with pid, which process id should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the order of creating processes? npm => /bin/sh => node /api/.. => node server/app.js ?

> What does each process do? All three processes are necessary to run my server?

Well, the flow is like this:

- NPM is spawned (you run it) inside your shell, npm itself runs with [NPX](https://github.com/npm/npx#readme) in order to [set the local path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).
- Your npm script spawns a process from a package called [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) for cross-OS environment variable setting.
- That process in turn spawns Node.js (after setting the environment variables)

That's why you see 3 processes. After your server itself run - only the actual server process is needed to run the server.

> If I wants to kill the server with pid, which process id should I use?

This one: `node server/app.js` - since that's your actual server, the others are just "utility processes" (one for the npm script you ran and the other for the environment variables").

---

It's worth mentioning that in general - servers are run inside containers or other orchestrators/managers that have built-in logic for restarting/killing the process. Typically the orchestrator sends SIGTERM to the process.